# Prevent display of raw HTML in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, render

Is there a way to prevent in React.js, raw HTML display before the CSS stylesheets are completely loaded. I'm using Webpack, Semantic-UI (react version) and React.js.

Is there an equivalent of ng-cloak (angular) in React ?

Here's the content of my webpack config file :

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin')

const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const DEBUG = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': `"${process.env.NODE_ENV}"`
  })
]
const assetsDir = process.env.ASSETS_DIR
const assetMapFile = process.env.ASSETS_MAP_FILE
const outputFile = DEBUG ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js'

if (!DEBUG) {
  plugins.push(new ManifestPlugin({
    fileName: assetMapFile
  }))
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }))
}

const config = {
  entry: {
    bundle: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client/index.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    noParse: [],
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: DEBUG
        }
      },
      {test:/.svg$/,loader:'url-loader',query:{mimetype:'image/svg+xml',
      name:'/semantic/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.svg'}},
      {test:/.woff$/,loader:'url-loader',query:{mimetype:'application/font-woff',
      name:'/semantic/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff'}},
      {test:/.woff2$/,loader:'url-loader',query:{mimetype:'application/font-woff2',
      name:'/semantic/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2'}},
      {test:/.[ot]tf$/,loader:'url-loader',query:{mimetype:'application/octet-stream',
      name:'/semantic/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf'}},
      {test:/.eot$/,loader:'url-loader',query:{mimetype:'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
      name:'/semantic/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot'}},
      { test: /\.png/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000&minetype=image/png" },
      { test: /\.jpg/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "semantic-ui" : path.resolve( __dirname, "../semantic/dist/semantic.min.css")
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', ".css"]
  },
  plugins,
  output: {
    filename: outputFile,
    path: DEBUG ? '/' : assetsDir,
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  }
}

if (DEBUG) {
  config.devtool = '#inline-source-map'
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.devtool = 'source-map'
}

module.exports = config
```

I got this error when I try to load my css from my component :

```
Cannot find module '/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css'
```

and the module exists.
I tried the exact same configuration without Webpack and import from component worked.

Comment: do you mean HTML that's defined outside of the root element of your React application?

Comment: No inside my main React application. But since I'm using webpack which seems to load css files after HTML, the rendering is first raw, then formatted with CSS.

Comment: This isn't default behaviour, can you post some code, webpack config + where in your app you're loading your stylesheets?

Comment: Sure. Actually, I don't import it directly in my code, I thought webpack would import the css automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct setup for a production deploy.

By default, Webpack turns your CSS into Javascript code that injects CSS tags in the page. This allows for hot CSS reloading. It's only appropriate for the development environment, obviously. You *should* be using this default behavior in dev, and *should not* be using it in production.

In production, you need to build a separate CSS file and load it normally with a `<style>` tag in your production HTML code. To tell Webpack to pull that out into a file, use the [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin), which your code requires but never uses.

You should maintain two Webpack config files, one for development which doesn't extract text (and doesn't minify/uglify, etc), and one for production, which correctly minifies, hashes names, extracts text, etc.

Comment: can you explain in detail what changes required in the config file?